# Usage of "forte" for "skill to be built"

Tags: word-usage, usage

Can we use "forte" in following sentence:

1. I am looking forward to building my *forte* in Biotechnology.
2. I am looking forward to building my *forte* as Biotechnologist.

Comment: _Forte_ is not the word you want to use here. It means "strong point" or "primary skill", but it is not at all idiomatic in your sentence.

Comment: I think if I will rephrase this statement as follows, then it will be correct:

I am looking forward to building Biotechnology as my forte. 

Can you please comment?

Comment: We use _forte_ to describe a primary skill which we have _already gained_, not one which we hope to gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [definition of forte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forte) is "one's strong point", or a particular talent or thing you do very well. Your forte **is** biotechnology, because you have worked to build your expertise in that field. You don't build or increase your forte. It's like a favorite color; you just have one (or don't have one).

An example of using "forte":

> The author's forte is making her characters seem so real that you forget they're fictional.

"Build my forte" isn't ungrammatical exactly, but it just isn't used that way. If we look at an NGram (and follow the links for each phrase to check the actual usage), the most common construction is some form of "to be" - "is my forte", "wasn't my forte", "used to be my forte", etc.

[image: NGram of "* my forte"]

Comment: As one can build his talent or foster the same; for example, a person who is naive in biotechnology can become an expert in the same after performing a thorough study of this field. In such a scenario, can't we say that he has built biotechnology as his forte?

Comment: @abhijeetpathak No, it's not typically used that way, although I don't think there is anything grammatically wrong with it. I wouldn't say "build his talent" either. You can build your skills or expertise.